# VB.NET : i need to get specific text from xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Language version (VB.Net)
Platform version (.NET 4)
Operating system (Windows 7 Ultimate)

i need to create tumblr downloader. and i think i can grab the image url using this xml link
http://fyeahsonnaeun.tumblr.com/api/read?start=1
i already using xelement / xmldocument to load the page but i dont know how to extract the image links

```
<photo-url max-width="1280">media.tumblr.com/1bbf0fd243f78727f51c6b79fe758ba8/tumblr_mw49olJwkB1qm4souo1_1280.jpg</photo-url>
```

i need to get the link between `<photo-url max-width="1280">...</photo-url>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vb.net+parse+xml

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. You can use the code below, this one uses `System.Xml.XmlDocument` class to read xml and assumes that what you want is the value of the root element.

```
Dim xml As String = "<photo-url max-width=""1280"">media.tumblr.com/1bbf0fd243f78727f51c6b79fe758ba8/tumblr_mw49olJwkB1qm4souo1_1280.jpg</photo-url>"

Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(xml)
Dim el As System.Xml.XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
Dim url As String = el.InnerText
```